# Catch a specific array column and write it to file

Tags: arrays, bash, perl, if-statement, awk

I have an array with data like this:

```
( "10.1.1.1 api sd1", "10.1.1.1 lst sd2" )
```

Is there a possible way to extract from the array the elements in the second column in each row and to put them into a file? E.g. in the above case the expected result will be:

```
api
lst
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the array and use `read` to capture 2nd column in each array entry:

```
ARRAY1=( "10.1.1.1 api sd1" "10.1.1.1 lst sd2" )

for i in "${ARRAY1[@]}"; do
   read -r _ b _ <<< "$i"
   echo "$b"
done > out.log

cat out.log
api
lst
```

Comment: I try similar way but without that: read -r _ b _ <<< "$i". Could you explain me please _ b _ actually is the second column to catch right?

Comment: Yes basically underscores are there to ignore 1st value and all values after 2nd column.

Comment: If you want those values as well then use: `read -r a b rest <<< "$i"`

Comment: Hey u could've used `awk '{print $2}'` to make it simpler.

Comment: Yes sure `awk '{print $2}' <<< "$s"` can also be used but why would it be simpler than `read` which is an internal shell bulletin as opposed to `awk` which is an external binary invocation.

Comment: it's simpler for viewing, nothing more. And OP already tagged it with `AWK`.

Comment: Yes as I wrote `awk` can also be used in place of `read` if taking out `read` make it more readable :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way in bash

```
ARRAY=( "10.1.1.1 api sd1" "10.1.1.1 lst sd2" )

for i in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    set -- $i
    echo "$2"
done
```

This method would be more suitable for file in which there are lots of fields as you can simply pick out the field you want without having to create lots of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try the perl script below:

**Perl Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ("10.1.1.1 api sd1", "10.1.1.1 lst sd2");    
my @columns = ();
foreach my $result (@array)
 {
   @columns = split /\s/, $result;
   print $columns[1] . "\n";         
    }
```

**Perl One Liner :**

If the array elements are taken into the input file (Input) then using perl one liner we can do as below

```
perl -lane "print $F[1]" Input
```